# How do i install minecraft through terminal

Tags: system-installation, minecraft

what terminal commands can i use to install Minecraft? i don't seem to be able to open the .jar minecraft file even after i checked the executive option.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/198476/how-to-install-minecraft-on-ubuntu-or-any-other-linux-distribution/) to install minicraft in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I was told that this is the way to do it via the terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T):

Then type in the following one by one.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

I have not tried this myself, but hope it helps.

Also found this link:
[Install](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/minecraft-installer-for-ubuntu)